# make a written line editable by the user

Tags: c#, mono

I am using C# in class building an Console Application using Mono in Xamarin. I have came across an issue i seem to not find any solutions to.

Is it possible to allow the user to edit an line written with `Console.Write()`?

For example:

The application outputs `Edit: Hello` and in that text only "Hello" can be edited and when the user keypresses on enter it saves it in a string.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the cursor position:

```
Console.Write("Edit: _____");
Console.SetCursorPosition(6, Console.CursorTop);
string text = Console.ReadLine();
```